# Convert multiple background images to an Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In CSS3 we can apply multiple background images to an element. I want to convert those multiple images into an Array.

```
<div style="background-image:url('dg.png'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))"> 
</div>
```

I tried in following way using Jquery

```
$("div").css("background-image").split(",")
```

unfortunately that doesn't work because linear gradient also has `,`'s. And I tried like this

```
 $("div").css('background-image').split("'),")
```

Ok fine worked, but I think it is not reliable, is there any reliable solution for this. It should give the final output like an Array as shown below.

```
 ["url('dg.png')",'linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))']
```

Comment: Do you own/maintain the HTML code?  If so why not start the background images off as an array, then combine them into the CSS attribute?  use a `for` loop to run through the array elements and append them plus a `, ` to the end of the background images attribute.

Comment: Is this really your inline style? It is not valid html/inline style at all? $("div").css("background-image") will not produce anything, in this case...

Comment: @sinisake Good catch. Did not initially notice the omission of a valid `css` property at `style` attribute.

Comment: @Joshua Are you trying to display both images?

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) methods of String:

```js
    var strs = [
  'url("dg.png"), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))',
  'url("dg2.png"), linear-gradient(to right, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))'
];
var results = [];
function recursive(strings) {
  var str = strings.shift();
  if (str) {
    var first = str.indexOf('url');
    var second = str.indexOf('linear-gradient');
    var firstPart = str.slice(0, second - 2);
    var result = [];
    result.push(firstPart);
    var secondPart = str.slice(second);
    result.push(secondPart);
    results.push(result);
    return recursive(strings);
  } 
  else {
    return results;
  }
}
console.log(recursive(strs));
```

Comment: great, but what if we have more than 2 backgrounds.

Comment: So you want to handle several backgrounds in different element, right?

Comment: Yes that's right, I am trying to put a for loop in your logic, so we can achieve it.

Comment: Ok, something like this?

Comment: Sorry, I had to modify my answer, hope it helps more now.

Comment: I think strs should not be an array it is like `url('dg.png'),url('ap.svg'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121),linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)`,  great help

Comment: I know what you mean but when you get all backgrounds via dom these look like this. strs is still array that has got two elements.

Answer (score 0):

As noted by @sinisake the `style` value is missing a valid `css` property.

You can adjust `html` to include newline characters at `style` attribute, use `RegExp` `/background-image:,\n\s+/` as parameter to `.split()` to split comma followed by newline character followed by one or more space charcters.

Note also, double quotes should not be inside double quotes. , Including quotes around URL passed to `css` `url()` function is not necessary; `url()` algorithm surrounds passed URL in quotes.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var backgrounds = document.querySelector("div")
                   .getAttribute("style")
                   .split(/background-image:|,\n\s+/)
                   .filter(Boolean);
                   
  console.log(backgrounds);
}
```

```css
#background {
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" 
     style='background-image:url("http://lorempixel.com/50/50"),
            linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))'> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML code is structured this way:

```
<div style="background-image:url('dg.png'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))"> 
</div>
```

you could try something like this:

```
   regex = /, (?=linear)|,(?=url)/g;
    arr=[];
    $( "div" ).each(function( i ) {
      arr[i]=$(this).css("background-image").split(regex);

    });
      console.log(arr)
```

```js
regex = /, (?=linear)|,(?=url)/g;
arr=[];
$( "div" ).each(function( i ) {
  arr[i]=$(this).css("background-image").split(regex);

});
  console.log(arr)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="background-image:url('dg.png'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))"> 
</div>
<div style="background-image:url('333.png'),url('ggg'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(200, 66, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))"> 
</div>
<div style="background-image:url('6666.png'),url('fff'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(202, 32, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121))"> 
</div>
```

EDIT: `regex = /, (?=linear)|,(?=url)/g;`

Comment: thank you, I ran a test case as below `str = "url('dg.png'),url('ap.svg'), linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121),linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)"
str.split(regex)` it is giving different result as  
`["url('dg.png'),url('ap.svg')", "linear-gradient(to left, rgb(178, 69, 146), rgb(241, 95, 121),linear-gradient(top, #fff, #000)"]`

Comment: Well, if you have multiple urls, then some additional conditions, for string checking is needed, or maybe more flexible regex....

Comment: @Joshna, please try new code/regex... now it should cover your test strings/styles too...

Answer (score 0):

Well, I am not good at RegEx so I wrote this program to split css `background-image` string. It can split background values like

- url()
- linear-gradient()
- radial-gradient()
- conic-gradient()
- repeating-linear-gradient()
- repeating-radial-gradient()
- repeating-conic-gradient()

```js
function splitBackgroundImage(value) {
    const splitted = value.split(/\),\s?/);

    const vals = splitted.reduce((acc, curr, i, arr) => {
        // String.prototype.split() method by default eliminates the delimiter; so I put it again
        if (i < arr.length - 1) curr = `${curr}), `;

        if (
            curr.includes('url(') ||
            curr.includes('linear-gradient(') ||
            curr.includes('radial-gradient(') ||
            curr.includes('conic-gradient(')
        ) {
            acc.push(curr.trim());
        } else if (i > 0) {
            // If it's not the start of a background-image value, then it must be a part of previous value
            acc[i - 1] = `${acc[i - 1]}${curr}`.trim();
        }

        return acc;
    }, []);

    return vals.map((val) => {
        if (val[val.length - 1] === ',') val = val.slice(0, -1);
        return val;
    });
}

console.log(splitBackgroundImage('url("http://hello.com"), url("http://hello.com"), repeating-conic-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, #000 100%), url("http://hello.com"), repeating-linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, #000 100%), linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, #000 100%), radial-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, #000 100%), repeating-radial-gradient(90deg, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9) 0%, #000 100%)'));
```